# Implementing wildcard at end of a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, wildcard

I looked through a number of posts (and other websites) and I seem to have a hit a roadblock.  I have the following array:

```
var data_dictionary = ["youtube.com", "facebook.com", "youtube.com/feed/subscriptions", "twitter.com"]
```

I'm trying to return data for everything that has youtube.com*.  Below is the relevant snippet of my function:

```
var result = []     
for (var i=0; i<data_dictionary.length; i++) {
   if (data_dictionary[i].page == /^youtube.com/) {
     result.push (data_dictionary[i].page,data_dictionary[i].share)
    }
 }
 break;       
}
return result
```

The problematic area is in the if clause (**/^youtube.com/**).  How can I receive the following return:

```
["youtube.com" , "youtube.com/feed/subscriptions"]
```

Comment: to compare against regex use `data_dictionary[i].page.match(/^youtube.com/)`

Comment: Works perfectly!  Great to learn this (very new to JS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method to filter array and **[`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)** to check for match.

```js
var data_dictionary = ["youtube.com", "facebook.com", "youtube.com/feed/subscriptions", "twitter.com"];

function check(data_dictionary) {
  return data_dictionary.filter(function(v) {
    return /^youtube\.com/.test(v);
    // using indexOf
    // v.indexOf('youtube.com') == 0;
  });
}
console.log(check(data_dictionary));
```

---

**FYI:** Your if condition will be only true if the string is `'/^youtube.com/'`. ie, `('/^youtube.com/' == /^youtube.com/) === true`. Your code will work if you changed the if condition to `/^youtube.com/.test(data_dictionary[i])`. Also in the provided data `page` and `share` properties are undefined only plain strings are the element.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same approach that you had before. However using ".filter" won't be a bad idea, but I will suggest you compare their benchmark

```
var data_dictionary = ["youtube.com", "facebook.com", "youtube.com/feed/subscriptions", "twitter.com"];
var pattern = /^youtube.com/;
var result = [];
var i = 0;

function loop (args) {
  for (i; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (pattern.test(args[i])) {
        result.push(args[i]);
    }
  }
 return result;
}

console.log(loop(data_dictionary)) // ["youtube.com" , "youtube.com/feed/subscriptions"]
```

Comparing the speed below I would suggest you use the approach above

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex here you can do like this;

```js
var data_dictionary = ["youtube.com", "facebook.com", "youtube.com/feed/subscriptions", "twitter.com"],
filtered = data_dictionary.filter(e => !!~e.indexOf("youtube.com") && e);
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(filtered) + "</pre>");
```

Or if you want a faster solution still with Array methods then

```js
var data_dictionary = ["youtube.com", "facebook.com", "youtube.com/feed/subscriptions", "twitter.com"],
filtered = data_dictionary.reduce((p,c) => !!~c.indexOf("youtube.com") ? p.concat(c):p,[]);
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(filtered) + "</pre>");
```